# Kill a large postgres pg_dump file import

Tags: postgresql

I am importing a large Postgresql dump file (2m+ rows) in Ubuntu (started the process via an Adminer "import") and am now regretting it as it is taking very long. It's the kind of dump file created by pg_dump that starts `COPY table (columnd, column) FROM stdin`. What is the safe way to kill this process now?

Regular kill is not doing anything. Nor is `pg_cancel_backend`. Tried `sudo pkill -u postgres` as well without success.
How can I stop this process now without crashing anything?

Comment: If none of those things worked (when tried correctly), then there is probably no way to stop it without crashing.  Can you attach to it with gdb and get a backtrace?  What does the status column show in `top` or `ps`?

Comment: Not sure what you're calling the status column. htop give:  PID, USER, PRI, NI, VIRT, RES, SHR, S, CPU%, MEM%, TIME+ & Command. Anyways restarted postgres and now it's stopped.

Comment: In `top` the status column is usually the one headed with 'S'